# try/catch on stack overflows in java?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Can you try/catch a stack overflow exception in java?  It seems to be throwing itself either way.  When my procedures overflows, I'd like to "penalize" that value.

Comment: prevention is better than catching....

Comment: catching is useful for debugging :)

Comment: Not ever making mistakes is better than debugging lol jk

Comment: Imagine you have a test that running 1000 test cases stored in a file. You may want to know which test case got the error first before preventing it...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Seems to work:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] argv){
        try{
            main(null);
        }
        catch(StackOverflowError e){
            System.err.println("ouch!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah I was trying with a generic exception.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree that finding out what is causing the exception and preventing it would be better though.

Comment: @stereos You weren't trying to catch `Exception` were you? `Error` extends `Throwable` directly, not through `Exception`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are getting a stack overflow, you are likely attempting infinite recursion or are severely abusing function invocations. Perhaps you might consider making some of your procedures iterative instead of recursive or double-check that you have a correct base case in your recursive procedure. Catching a stack overflow exception is a bad idea; you are treating the symptoms without addressing the underlying cause.

Comment: In the case of the use of recursion and overflow of the set options of the JVM the SO is a normal negative answer of a correct program. We MUST catch it and react. For example, in the case of lazy sequence, set by a recursive finction(http://stackoverflow.com/a/33926444/715269), we could simply move on by smaller steps.

Comment: Catching the SO error is also useful for debugging when you don't know which one of many recursive methods is causing the SO error :)

Comment: I agree if the stack overflow is caused by your code. I'm currently fighting a stack overflow that is caused by user data, which is processed by a library I use. So I can't do anything to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

You have to catch an Error, not the Exception

Answer (score 4):

The functional features of Java 8 makes this question incomparably more important. For while we start to use recursion massively, StackOverflowException is something we MUST count for.

The Java 8 lambdas types has no one among them that throws StackOverflowException. So, we have to create such. It is absolutely necessary, without that we won't pass even the IDE control.

For example, Integer -> Integer function type could look as:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SoFunction <U> {
    public U apply(Integer index) throws StackOverflowException;
}
```

After that we can write a function that will accept lambdas throwing StackOverflowException.

```
public T get(int currentIndex) throws StackOverflowException{
```

And only now we can create a recursive lambda:

```
fiboSequence.setSequenceFunction(
            (i) ->
            fiboSequence.get(i-2).add(fiboSequence.get(i-1))
);
```

After that we can call the recursive chain `fiboSequence.get(i)`and get a result or a StackOverflowException if the whole chain was incomputable.

***In the case of use of recursion SO gets absolutely different meaning: you have jumped too deep, repeat it dividing in more shallow steps.***

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's just required due to the nature of the code to increase the (OS dependent) stack size, which is usually 1m per thread on Linux.

If you are happy that the code is optimized for your use case and still hit this error then increase the stack size for the VM using -Xss2m for example - See the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp1024112)