# Java generate random solution

Tags: java, random, stack

I am doing scheduling system and it will produce a random timetable, due to random method it will cause some of the exam can't add to the timetable and it will result stack over flow error.....
but sometime it will able to produce a complete timetable.

So I want to ask here how can i do like this:

```
if result == stack over flow error {
    redo the function
}
```

Comment: You should fix stackoverflow error.

Comment: It's a very bad idea. If you have a stack overflow error, then it's because you have too much calls on the stack (recursivity?). Use a different implementation (a.k.a replace recursivity by a loop and a stack collection).

Comment: that error is can't be avoided because exam is random add to timetable it's depend on luck

Comment: Trust me: it can be avoided.

Comment: This should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535723/try-catch-on-stack-overflows-in-java

Comment: The reason of the stackoverflow error is because some of the remaining exams cannot find a suitable timeslot. Thus it keep finding.

Comment: Post your algorithm. We'll show you how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad idea to have stackoverflow error in your program and change the flow of execution using catch.
But if you want to do so you can surround your code in `try catch` block like this.

```
try{
//your code that is likely to produce stackoverflow error
}
catch(StackOverflowError se)
{
//do whatever you want after stackover flow.
}
```

Comment: may i know what se does?

Comment: whatever is thrown by the try block must be caught by the catch block so you have to specify a reference name in which you're getting that object that is thrown by the try block.In this case I specified name as se in which i'm getting object thrown by try block.

Comment: you can read exception handling in java here http://www.javatpoint.com/exception-handling-in-java

Answer (score -1):

Catch the StackOverflowError exception.

```
boolean success = true;
do {
  try {
     success = true;
     someRecursiveFunction();
  } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
     success = false;
  }
} while (!success);
```

Comment: This is NOT a solution. Errors are meant to crash the JVM.

Comment: "An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch." - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

Comment: You're answering the question, but then the OP will think this is a neat idea.

Comment: Yeah, I answered this first, got downvote, and another answered like this, not only accepted, but also not downvoted. Today really is a bad day for me.