# Is it possible to create in Java 8 a unlimitedly growing in lazy way collection, defined by recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, closures, java-stream

I can create a recursive closure:

```
static IntUnaryOperator fibo;
fibo = 
    (i) -> 
    i<2 ? 1 : fibo.applyAsInt(i-1)+ fibo.applyAsInt(i-2);
```

But of course, it has sense only as an example. To be useful, such collection should keep already once counted elements and get() them without recounting. The counting of elements should happen in lazy way, at first need. Thus, no member will have to be calculated more than once. In such way we'll a structure that will look like a recursively defined sequence, and will be fast and reusable.

When I started to study Java 8 I thought that Stream works in that way. But it does not, for the stream cannot be used twice.

I thought about the following construction:

```
IntStream fi;
fi=IntStream.iterate(0, i -> fi[i-1]+fi[i-2]);
```

But that way it won't work - I can't get an item from the stream by index.The other problem is that if I'll later go along the stream, it will be consumed and I can't use it repeatedly. If I copy the stream to List, it is not lazy anymore.

As a result, I need some construction that I can address by index. As `fibo(i)`.

Edit. Obviously, the solution cannot be a stream, for the stream cannot be used twice. I don't want to repeat all calculations on every call to F(i).

Comment: You probably want to create a `Spliterator.OfInt`

Comment: @fge I don't need sequental access. It can be done easier by generation of an array.

Comment: An array is not lazy by definition and cannot be infinite either; I'm really not sure what you are asking as a result

Comment: @fge Notice the title of the question - lazy and *iterative*. If you use sequental access, it is not iterative... Java array is not lazy, but I can fill it by references that will be filled only when used for the first time. Thus it becomes lazy. It is simple, only too long. And no use for Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will be created as a class `FunctionalSequence` for representation of a lazy, infinite sequence of objects, defined by a lambda function with integer argument. The function can be iterative or not. For the iterative case the `FunctionalSequence` class will have a method `initialize` for setting the start values.

The declaration of an object of such class will look so:

```
    FunctionalSequence<BigInteger> fiboSequence =  new FunctionalSequence<>();
    fiboSequence.
        initialize(Stream.of(BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ONE)).
        setSequenceFunction(
            (i) ->
            fiboSequence.get(i-2).add(fiboSequence.get(i-1))
        );
```

Notice, as in the recursive lambda example in the question, we cannot declare the object and define it recursively in one operator. One operator for declaration, another for definition.

The `FunctionalSequence` class definition:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FunctionalSequence<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    LinkedList<CountedFlighweight<T>> realList = new LinkedList<>();
    StackOverflowingFunction<Integer, T> calculate = null;
    public FunctionalSequence<T> initialize(Stream<T> start){
        start.forEachOrdered((T value) ->
        {
                realList.add(new CountedFlighweight<>());
                realList.getLast().set(value);
        });
        return this;
    }
    public FunctionalSequence<T>  setSequenceFunction(StackOverflowingFunction<Integer, T> calculate){
        this.calculate = calculate;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new SequenceIterator();
    }
    public T get(int currentIndex) throws StackOverflowError{
        if(currentIndex < 0) return null;
        while (currentIndex >= realList.size()){
            realList.add(new CountedFlighweight<T>());
        }
        try {
            return (T) realList.get(currentIndex).get(calculate, currentIndex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class SequenceIterator implements Iterator<T>{
        int currentIndex;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T result = null;
            if (currentIndex == realList.size()){
                realList.add(new CountedFlighweight<T>());
            }
            // here the StackOverflowError catching is a pure formality, by next() we would never cause StackOverflow
            try {
                result = realList.get(currentIndex).get(calculate, currentIndex);
            } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            }
            currentIndex++;
            return result;
        }

    }
    /**
     * if known is false, the value of reference is irrelevant
     * if known is true, and reference is not null, reference contains the data
     * if known is true, and reference is null, that means, that the appropriate data are corrupted in any way
     * calculation on corrupted data should result in corrupted data.
     * @author Pet
     *
     * @param <U>
     */
    public class CountedFlighweight<U>{
        private boolean known = false;
        private U reference;
        /**
         * used for initial values setting 
         */
        private void set(U value){
            reference = value;
            known = true;
        }
        /**
         * used for data retrieval or function counting and data saving if necessary
         * @param calculate
         * @param index
         * @return
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public U get(StackOverflowingFunction<Integer, U> calculate, int index) throws StackOverflowError{
            if (! known){
                if(calculate == null) {
                    reference = null;
                } else {
                    try {
                        reference = calculate.apply(index);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        reference = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            known = true;
            return reference;
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface StackOverflowingFunction <K, U> {
        public U apply(K index) throws StackOverflowError;

    }
}
```

As the recursive function could easily meet the StackOverflowError, we should organize the recursion so that in that case the whole recursive sequence will roll back without any changes really met and throw the exception.

The use of the FunctionalSequence could look so:

```
    // by iterator:
    int index=0;
    Iterator<BigInteger> iterator = fiboSequence.iterator(); 
    while(index++<10){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

Or so:

```
static private void tryFibo(FunctionalSequence<BigInteger> fiboSequence, int i){
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long endTime;
    try {
        fiboSequence.get(i);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("repeated timing for f("+i+")=" + (endTime-startTime)/1000000.+" ns");
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("failed counting f("+i+"), time=" + (endTime-startTime)/1000000.+" ns");
    }       
}
```

The last function can be used in the following way:

```
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 1100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 200);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 1100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 2100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 2100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 1100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 100);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 200);
    tryFibo(fiboSequence, 1100);
```

Here are the results (the stack was limited to 256K for the needs of testing):

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
failed counting f(1100), time=3.555689 ns
repeated timing for f(100)=0.213156 ns
repeated timing for f(100)=0.002444 ns
repeated timing for f(200)=0.266933 ns
repeated timing for f(1100)=5.457956 ns
repeated timing for f(2100)=3.016445 ns
repeated timing for f(2100)=0.001467 ns
repeated timing for f(1100)=0.005378 ns
repeated timing for f(100)=0.002934 ns
repeated timing for f(100)=0.002445 ns
repeated timing for f(200)=0.002445 ns
repeated timing for f(1100)=0.003911 ns
```

Look, the repeatable call of the f(i) for the same index takes practically no time - no iterations were made. We cannot reach f(1100) at once because of the StackOverflowError. But after we have reached once f(200), f(1100) becomes reachable. We made it!

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are asking for something like this:

```
public class Fibonacci extends AbstractList<BigInteger> {
    @Override
    public Stream<BigInteger> stream() {
        return Stream.iterate(new BigInteger[]{ BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE },
           p->new BigInteger[]{ p[1], p[0].add(p[1]) }).map(p -> p[0]);
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<BigInteger> iterator() {
        return stream().iterator();
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    @Override
    public BigInteger get(int index) {
        return stream().skip(index).findFirst().get();
    }
}
```

It’s accessible via the `List` interface (it doesn’t implement `RandomAccess` for a good reason), thus, you may ask for the n’th value via `get(n)`. Note that the implementation of `get` hints how you can get values at positions after `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Just use `stream().skip(position).findFirst().get()`.

Beware! This list is *infinite*, as you asked for. Don’t ask it for things that operate on all elements, e.g. not even `toString()`. But things like the following will work smoothly:

```
System.out.println(new Fibonacci().subList(100, 120));
```

or

```
for(BigInteger value: new Fibonacci()) {
    System.out.println(value);
    if(someCondition()) break;
}
```

However, when you have to process large sequences of elements and want to do it efficiently, you should ensure to work on the iterator or stream to avoid `O(n²)` complexity of repeated `get` calls.

Note that I changed the element type to `BigInteger` as it would be pointless to think about infinite streams when it comes to the Fibonacci sequence and the `int` or `long` value type. Even with the `long` value type, the sequence is over after only 92 values as then, overflow occurs.

---

Update: now that you made clear that you are looking for a lazy *storage*, you may change the class above as follows:

```
public class Fibonacci extends AbstractList<BigInteger> {
    final Map<BigInteger,BigInteger> values=new HashMap<>();

    public Fibonacci() {
        values.put(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE);
        values.put(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger get(int index) {
        return get(BigInteger.valueOf(index));
    }
    public BigInteger get(BigInteger index) {
        return values.computeIfAbsent(index, ix ->
            get(ix=ix.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).add(get(ix.subtract(BigInteger.ONE))));
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<BigInteger> stream() {
        return Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ZERO, i->i.add(BigInteger.ONE)).map(this::get);
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<BigInteger> iterator() {
        return stream().iterator();
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

I used `BigInteger` as key/index here to fulfill the requirement to be (theoretically) infinite, though we can use a `long` key as well for all practical uses. The key point is the initially empty storage: (now exemplary using `long`):

```
final Map<Long,BigInteger> values=new HashMap<>();
```

which is pre-initialized with the values that should end each recursion (unless it ends earlier due to already computed values):

```
values.put(1L, BigInteger.ONE);
values.put(0L, BigInteger.ONE);
```

Then, we can ask for a lazily computed value via:

```
public BigInteger get(long index) {
    return values.computeIfAbsent(index, ix -> get(ix-1).add(get(ix-2)));
}
```

or a stream delegating to the `get` method described above:

```
LongStream.range(0, Long.MAX_VALUE).mapToObj(this::get);
```

This creates a stream that is only “practically infinite” whereas the complete example class above, using `BigInteger` is theoretically infinite…

The `Map` will remember every computed value of the sequence.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, this is a very interesting piece of code, but not what I am talking about. If we had really a lazy collection, then the recursion would calculate any its item only once. So, the complexity would be at worst O(n), if we asked the first time for F(n).

Comment: Because the stream is consumed, this code has complexity O(n) EACH TIME we ask for F(n).  It is very far form being optimal.

Comment: @Gangnus: A stream is not a storage. Even if you could use a stream multiple times, it wouldn’t turn into a storage, each query still had `O(n)`. If you want to *store calculated values*, you should include that into your question.

Comment: Yes. And I had not asked for a stream. And I had explained why the stream is not a solution.

Comment: But anyway, you have a nice stream, surely useful. But not for this question. Sorry

Comment: If the question could be understood wrongly, it shall be understood wrongly. You are right. I edited the question. I bring my excuses.

Comment: Never mind. Hope my updated answer brings you closer to your goal.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think up a good general solution, but if you want to access specifically two previous elements, this could be done in quite easy way defining the custom `Spliterator` like this:

```
public static IntStream iterate(int first, int second, IntBinaryOperator generator) {
    Spliterator.OfInt spliterator = new AbstractIntSpliterator(Long.MAX_VALUE, 
                                             Spliterator.ORDERED) {
        int prev1 = first, prev2 = second;
        int pos = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
            if(pos < 2) {
                action.accept(++pos == 1 ? prev1 : prev2);
            } else {
                int next = generator.applyAsInt(prev1, prev2);
                prev1 = prev2;
                prev2 = next;
                action.accept(next);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.intStream(spliterator, false);
}
```

Usage:

```
iterate(1, 1, Integer::sum).limit(20).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: 1. It is consumed by use. 2. The usage is only a bit shorter than the whole code for closure iteration.

Comment: And how I use it if I need fibo(i)?

Comment: @Gangnus, `iterate(1, 1, Integer::sum).skip(i-1).findFirst().get()`.