# Java show me long error but missing in my log file

Tags: java, logging, console

Hi all I know its a stupid question but I'm trying everything.
My game server show me a very long error which is too long for console and can see the top of it, but it is missing from my log and I can't see the details of this error.
 
Can somebody help me on how can I capture that error:

```
private void fix(L2PcInstance pl, int playerPoints)
{
    try
    {
        IAchievement arc = Achievements.getInstance().GetAchivment(_id, pl.getAchivmentLevelbyId(_id) + 1);
        if ((arc != null) && (playerPoints > arc.getNeedPoints()))
        {
            Achievements.getInstance().reward(pl, arc);
            fix(pl, playerPoints);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.error(getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Error in fix: " + e);
    }
}
```

the error
[image: error console]

the line 96 is

```
fix(pl, playerPoints);
```

but the error is missing from my log im try to capture the console to txt file from command

java myserver.jar > capturemyconsole.txt but again it's showing error in console that the txt is missing. How is this possible ? Thanks for your time and help :)
and sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: we need the msg not the screen shot

Comment: this is the error error is too long and can be coppy can coppy only this in the picture

Comment: I would guess this is a stackoverflow. You call fix() again and again based on some condition. But you never change the variables that have influence to the condition so it can become false at some point.

Comment: try `java myserver.jar 2> capturemyconsole.txt`. Exception and errors are printed on `System.err` by default.

Comment: this method is called fix in my source im not change for the post thanks bracco23 will try

Answer (score 0):

You method `fix` calls itself, with the same arguments, causing stack overflow...

Should add some modification to the arguments, or some more condition to the recursion...

Comment: In fact, there should be argument modifications, and a base case, so you can stop the recursion.

Comment: this method is the real name "fix" fix method fixed in game the point on player its real name of the method

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by this method is fixed in game. Could you please try the command in comment of bracco23 and show us the root of the stacktrace? If this really is a stackoverflow and the program is meant to work the way you source code describes it, you may should think of your overall design e.g. calling fix() in a loop and not via recursion.

Comment: yes im try now wait for the error i dont know when show thanks for fast anwser

Answer (score 0):

You can catch "Error" instead of "Exception" and then log

```
[...] catch (Error e)
{
    _log.error(getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Error in fix: " + e, e);
}
```

In Your current code StackOverflowException (which is not a child of Exception) is propagated without going into catch block. Remember to put additional "e" parameter to log full stacktrace.
It's not a good practice to catch Error, but it'll answer Your question.

More info: [try/catch on stack overflows in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535723/try-catch-on-stack-overflows-in-java)